# ffmpeg package loss during *local* transcoding

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, transcode, packet-loss, local-storage

I'm trying to transcode videos with outdated codecs/containers, mostly .wmv or .avi files.
The following ffmpeg (v6.1.1) command works and produces a working .mp4 file that doesn't *seem* to present any issue or playback glitches:

```
ffmpeg -i olFile.wmv -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac -q:a 100 newFile.mp4
```

Going through the output I noticed a couple packet loss errors in some cases.

> [wmapro @ 00000140df439ac0] Packet loss detected! seq 8 vs 0bitrate=9865.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=   1x
> [wmapro @ 00000140df439ac0] Packet loss detected! seq c vs 0bitrate=8126.7kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=   1x

This happens when transcoding, both over LAN and on local storage. It's also reproducible, meaning that encoding the same file again produces the same packet loss error count at the same position in the output.

Trying to gather information proved virtually fruitless, the [few things](https://superuser.com/questions/1321149/why-am-i-getting-lost-packets-in-ffmpeg-doing-local-rtp-streaming) I found turned out to be inconsequential in solving this. Both the `-re` and `-readrate` parameters changed nothing.

So...

**Why does this happen?**
*I'm new to ffmpeg, does it pipe everything through TCP/UDP even when processing something locally?

Random network PL isn't reproducible in my experience, so I'm wondering if these might be non-network related.*

**Can this be safely ignored?**
*Doubt it can, but if these packets are caused by something "corrupted" in the input file,

I wouldn't be able to do anything about it anyways.*

**Can this be solved?**
*Some arcane parameter or something similar? As long as it doesn't involve messing with the OS network settings.*

Comment: "Packet loss detected" means that the input file has a missing packed ("missing packed" refers to missing encoded video frame or missing encoded audio frame, and not TCP/UDP packet). It means the the sequence of encoded frames is incomplete, and at least one encoded frame (i.e packet) is missing. There are cases when the warning is false, and nothing is missing. Sometimes it's just one or two packets at the end of the file. Try other input file.

Comment: Thank you @Rotem, that's already very helpful. If I understand this correctly, a couple of these errors, even in the middle of the file, should be safe to ignore. Worst case, a couple of frame will be missing, but the file should be playable. Am I right?

Comment: Right, it's just a warning... Since I don't know what causes the issue in the first place, I can't say for sure if it's going to be noticeable in the transcoded output (probably not).